# Size a window relative to the size of the screen the window is in (in case of multiple displays) in SDL2

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm writing some code which wraps parts of SDL2. I want to handle a case where a window is moved to another display after it's created, scaling up the window appropriately.

I'm using C.

The part I can't figure out is how to, given an `SDL_Window` object, find out which display that window is in, on a multi-display setup. If I can find that out, it's trivial to find the size of that display and set the window size appropriately.

```
// Width and height of display that myWindow is in (myWindow some previously created SDL_Window)
int disp_x_size_px;
int disp_y_size_px;

/* Need code to get values for disp_x_size_px and disp_y_size_px.
    With these values I can set the window size correctly. */
```

Comment: @Fredrik: Yup, but you *can* pass in `SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN` to `SDL_CreateWindow()`'s `flags` argument, position/size it, then use `SDL_RaiseWindow()` to show it.

Comment: Did `SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex()` + `SDL_GetDisplayBounds()` + `SDL_SetWindowPosition()` not work?

Comment: @Fredrik sorry, my explanation was unclear. The window gets created in display 0 by default, I intend to change the actual size based on the size of the current display it's in, after the creation, i.e. after it gets moved to another display. I suppose there is also potential for the window to be created in another display, though then one would know which one. I will edit my question to fix this. Nevertheless, genpfault's comment solved my problem.

Comment: @genpfault Thank you! I wasn't able to find this `SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex` function earlier. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From genpfault's comment, the answer is to use `SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex()` to get the display a window is on. Then of course `SDL_GetDisplayBounds()` can be used to get the display size and `SDL_SetWindowPosition()` to set the window position appropriately.

<sub>Note: I'm putting this in an answer so this question can have an accepted answer: it has been answered acceptably, after all.</sub>